# Cassandra select query with timezone issue

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh, spark-cassandra-connector, cassandra-2.1

We have two different cassandra cluster on two different timezones.

- Cluster1: 2.1.8 version, with IST TZ
- Cluster2: 2.1.9 version, with UTC TZ

On cluster1 for a select query with timestamp column, i need not mention the tz[+0530] value , whereas on the other cluster I must and should provide the TZ value in select query to fetch the row. Is it to do with cassandra version?

I use cqlsh to do the query part. I tried cqlshrc file option, which only changes the format of output.

cluster1:

```
select * from test.check where row_timestamp = '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
```

cluster2:

```
select * from test.check where row_timestamp = '1970-01-01 00:00:00+0000';
```

IF no TZ is mentioned, i get "0" rows. 
I dont want to give TZ in cluster2, please adivce how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit strange, I must admit, but there might been some changes in time zone manipulation between 2.1.8 and 2.1.9. This is from the changelog:

> (cqlsh) Fix timestamps before 1970 on Windows, always    use UTC for
>   timestamp display (CASSANDRA-10000)

On the other hand, the documentation is quite clear on this issue:

> If no time zone is specified, the time zone of the Cassandra
>   coordinator node handing the write request is used. For accuracy,
>   DataStax recommends specifying the time zone rather than relying on
>   the time zone configured on the Cassandra nodes.

So, my sincere recommendation is to specify the time zone, and specify the same, presumably GMT (or UTC time). Save yourself the headache. [Mind, GMT is not exactly equal to UTC, there is a slight difference in meaning](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html). That way, you should ignore the time zone settings on the clusters. The time stamp is ultimately stored as a number of milliseconds (from certain point). The time zone information is purely a "rendering" thing. The number of milliseconds passed is the same in, for example `2015/03/05 14:00:00+0100` and `2015/03/05 16:00:00+0300`.

If you are specifying nothing, and getting 0 results, while you do get results when you use +0000, then make sure that the data you are expecting originally is written with the expected time zone. Maybe there actually is not any data in the span because of that, or the coordinating node time stamp is different.

Comment: Thanks for this, it turned out to be the version change.